# props are undefined in react component. How to use getServerSideProps properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My problem is props from getServerSideProps is undefined when i pass them in react component.

I try pass props from getServerSideProps in react component but props is undefined. It seems that code is correct, on the backend everything works, but i can't figure out why it is undefined??

Here is my code:

```
export default function CardFeature({ books = [] }) {
  const [visibleBooks, setVisibleBooks] = useState(books.slice(0, 4));
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
  const [translateX, setTranslateX] = useState(0);

  const handleNextSlide = () => {
    if (currentSlide < books.length - 4) {
      setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 4);
      setVisibleBooks(books.slice(currentSlide + 1, currentSlide + 8));
      setTranslateX(translateX - window.innerWidth / 2);
    }
  };

  const handlePrevSlide = () => {
    if (currentSlide >= 4) {
      setCurrentSlide(currentSlide - 4);
      setVisibleBooks(books.slice(currentSlide - 4, currentSlide));
      setTranslateX(translateX + window.innerWidth / 2);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="book-carousel-container">
      <div className="arrow__left" onClick={handlePrevSlide}>
        <FaChevronLeft />
      </div>
      <div className="arrow__right" onClick={handleNextSlide}>
        <FaChevronRight />
      </div>
      <div className="window__card" style={{ transform: `translateX(${translateX}px)` }}>
        {visibleBooks.map((book) => (
          <div className="card__feature" key={book._id}>
            <div className="card__image-feature">
              <img src={book.image} width={"110px"} height={"150px"} alt={book.title} />
            </div>
            <div className="card__info-feature">
              <h3>{book.title}</h3>
              <p>{book.author}</p>
              <div className="price__feature">
                <span>{book.price}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="button__basket-feature">
                <button type="button" className="button__basket-feature">
                  +
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/books");
    const data = await response.json();
    const books = data.books;
    return {
      props: {
        books,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return {
      props: {
        books: [],
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your definition of your component to

```
export default function CardFeature({ books }) {}
```

Also, use your debugger to find out what it's returned from the API.

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/books");
const data = await response.json();
const books = data.books;
```